# ParseQuery.whereContainedIn() returning no results

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

First, I am aware that a similar question has been asked before about whereContainedIn() vs whereMatches(), but this did not solve my problem. I am trying to implement a simple search algorithm where a ParseQuery checks if any one keyword is present in the content(I later then validify if it has at least 50% of the keywords). However, when I call query.whereContainedIn() and then query.count() the count is returned as 0 even though it should return one. I have an essay in the  database which has the text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...... and my search keyword is lorem. Code below:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Essays");
String[] keywords = text.toLowerCase().split(" ");
final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(keywords));
String TAG = "mishare";
Log.d(TAG, "doQuery: " + Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
final ArrayList<Essay> rvList = new ArrayList<>();
query.whereContainedIn("content", list);
done = false;
try {
    count = query.count();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have checked before and made sure that the keywords in the String array and ArrayList are valid and correctly entered

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I figured out that instead of using `query.whereContainedIn()` I could simply use `query.whereMatches()` to make it work.